# pycharm (python) shows functions in different colour - sometimes white, sometime yellow - why is that?

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

[image: no colour]

[image: with colour]

I wonder since days, why that happens, maybe I search with the wrong keywords

Comment: Show a full code with that so we can copy-paste and see that happens. It's hard to tell like that. It might be because of some error you have before that function that confuses the parser. It might be that it just needs time to update the formatting of the file. Who knows? Until we can see it for ourselves, it's just guessing. Provide a [mre] of the problem

Comment: if there are misspellings in your variables/functions names, it will underline them

Comment: In pycharm these lines(underlines) have some meaning like some typo error or syntax error and many more to learn more please visit this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html#editor

Comment: Which coding tool/IDE you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, PyCharm is showing a weak warning in that line. If you press `Alt + Enter` on that line, it will give you the possible suggestions for resolving the warning.

As far as I know, this warning may be of not having a docstring for the function.
If you want you can turn this off in settings.